# How to get html code from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is my node js code

```
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

If I console.log('body'), I will get all html code from this request, how ever, what can I do if I only want to have some code part of it?

For example, I only want to have html under a div with id="test" ?

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing and traversing the HTML code using Cheerio: https://cheerio.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Look into XPath and use that to help you locate the specific div.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp